# Xpath of button fails intermittantly

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need a help to find xpath of proceed to checkout button. This is my HTML:

```html
<ul class="checkout-types">
<li>
  <button type="button" title="Proceed to Checkout" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" onclick="window.location='http://www.utsavfashion.in/checkout/onepage/';">
    <span>Proceed to Checkout</span>
  </button>
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'checkout-types')//*/li/contains(@title, 'Proceed to Checkout')]"))
  .click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*/button[text()='Proceed to Checkout']"))
  .click();
```

But both approaches intermittently work/fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `By.cssSelector()` with [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait until element visible and enable to click as below :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn-proceed-checkout[title='Proceed to Checkout']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout'][.//span[contains(text(), 'Proceed to Checkout')]]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//*/button/*/span[text()='Proceed to Checkout']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following selectors:

Css:

```
button.btn-proceed-checkout.btn-checkout
button.btn-proceed-checkout[onclick*='checkout/onepage']
```

Xpath:

```
//button[contains(@class, 'btn-proceed-checkout')]
//button[contains(@class, 'btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout')]
//button[contains(@class, 'btn-proceed-checkout')][contains(@onclick, 'checkout/onepage')]
```